# the kernel of surjective homomorphism between topological groups is closed

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups, group-homomorphism

Suppose $\varphi : G\to H$ is a surjective homomorphism of topological groups, then $K=ker\varphi$ is a closed normal subgroup of $G$. If $G$ is compact, then $\varphi' : G/K\to H$ is an open map.

It is straightforward to me that $K$ is a normal subgroup, could some tell me why $K$ is closed and why if $G$ is compact then $\varphi'$ is open?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming that either topological groups are always Hausdorff or (equivalently) $\{e\}$ is always a closed set?

Comment: No, there is no Hausdorff assumption on topological groups.

Comment: What about the assumption that $\{e\}$ is closed?  Without this, the theorem is false.  (Give $\mathbb{Z}$ the indiscrete topology with only two open sets.)

Comment: No, I don't think so. It is actually the Proposition 1.7 in chapter 0 of the book "Introduction to compact transformation groups, Bredon", the book does not provide proof and seems that there is no additional assumptions.

Comment: I'm fairly sure Bredon assumes points are closed.

Comment: on page 1 of the book, Bredon says "a topological group is a HAUSDORFF space $G$ with...." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Oh, I missed it. I found that somewhere else, a topological group is not defined as a Hausdorff space, so I thought it has no Hausdorff assumption. Thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\ker\varphi=\varphi^{-1}\bigl(\{e_H\}\bigr)$, since $\varphi$ is continuous and since $\{e_H\}$ is a closed set, $\ker\varphi$ is a closed set.

If $G$ is compact, then $\varphi'$ is a continuous bijection with compact domain. Therefore, it is a homeomorphism (it maps closed sets into closed sets); in particular, it is an open map.